# Updating Results of a Fetch API Call in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I am new to NextJS and I am trying to figure out the best way to make a fetch api call to an api whose data is dynamic (i.e., it is constantly being updated).  What I need to do is the following:

1. Regularly make a call to the api and retrieve the latest articles
2. Add those retrieved articles to the previous articles that were retrieved

I should note that I do not need to save these articles long-term.  I need them for about a week or two, at which point I can erase them.

I am wondering, therefore, what is the best way to do this in NextJS.  Should I save each call to a database, an array?  Something else?

I'd appreciate any advice both on how to approach this as well as any links to documentation and/or tutorials showing me how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: it is pretty obvious that you can not store data on client-side expect some little data like token or small data in the cookie or local storage, so you need a back endpoint to store data.

Answer (score 0):

As @Afsanefda mentioned it isn't possible to reliably persist data on the client side. Therefore you need a place where you persist the data and there are myriad possibilities to do that.
I normally go with a managed database (like [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)).
With Next.js you've the possibility to create simple [API endpoints](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#api-routes) which could communicate with your database.